# Variable is not defined in different functions

Tags: python, function

Whenever I input a value, I am told that the variable is not defined. I am pretty sure that this is because of the two functions being separate, but I don't know how exactly to tie them together. The user should input only R, S, or U for gr and a number larger than zero for gal.

For example, if I input S, I get this: NameError: name 'S' is not defined

```
 #gas1.py

def main():
    gr=eval(input("\nEnter the gas grade. R for Regular, S for Special, U for Super: "))

    while (gr!=R or gr!=S or gr!=U):
        gr=eval(input("\nGas Grade must be R, S, or U. Enter the gas grade. R for Regular, S for Special, U for Super: "))
    gal=eval(input("Enter the number of gallons: "))
    while (gal<0):
        gal=eval(input("\nNumber of gallons must be greater than zero. Enter the number of gallons: "))


def gasCost(gr, gal):
    if gr==R:
        cost=2.49*gal
        print("You purchased", gal, "gallons of Regular gas at $2.49 per gallon.")
        print("Your payment is $", format(cost, "0.2f"))
    elif gr==S:
        cost=2.79*gal
        print("You purchased", gal, "gallons of Special gas at $2.79 per gallon.")
        print("Your payment is $", format(cost, "0.2f"))
    else:
        cost=2.99*gal
        print("You purchased", gal, "gallons of Super gas at $2.99 per gallon.")
        print("Your payment is $", format(cost, "0.2f"))




main()
```

Comment: Where do you learn to use `eval` from? `R`, `S` and `U` are not variables, but string literals which need to be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Is gas grade a character? If so, you need to remove eval().

The codes should be something looks like this I guess:

```
    gr=input("\nEnter the gas grade. R for Regular, S for Special, U for Super: ")
    while (gr!='R' or gr!='S' or gr!='U'):
        gr=input("\nGas Grade must be R, S, or U. Enter the gas grade. R for Regular, S for Special, U for Super: ")
    gal=eval(input("Enter the number of gallons: "))
    while (gal<0):
        gal=eval(input("\nNumber of gallons must be greater than zero. Enter the number of gallons: "))
```